# How to remove Windows 8 "tip box"

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1

How to remove the "tip box" that pops up from time to time on the desktop. I installed Windows 8 on VMWare on my Mac and there is no touch screen. It seems if I'm not doing what it suggest, it will not close. And I cannot "swipe" on the virtual machine..

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[Eightforums posted a guide](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/31098-help-tips-enable-disable-windows-8-1-a.html) on how to do remove them

Run the **Group Policy Editor** (`gpedit.msc`), go to `User Configuration->Administrative Templates->Windows Components->Edge UI` and set the option `Disable help tips` to `enabled`.

[image]

Now log off and login again and the tips are gone.

Comment: Another option is to disable touch support in the virtualisation software. A lot of virtualisation software emulates touches instead of mouse movements, which interferes with some parts of Win8.